# Hash in coldfusion for secure payment gateway

Tags: hash, coldfusion, payment-gateway

I am trying to create a hash password in coldfusion for our secure payment gateway to accept a transaction.

Unfortunately the payment gateway is refusing to accept my generated hash.

The form sends through all the elements of the transaction and sends a generated hash based on five different fields.

In PHP it is-:

```
<?php
echo hash('sha256', '
test_site1234
GBP
OrderTotal
OrderID
PASSWORD
');;
?>
```

Am I right in thinking the code in coldfusion should be -:

```
    <cfset sitesecurity = Hash("test_site1234"&"GBP"&#OrderTotal#&#URL.ThisOrderID#&"PASSWORD", "SHA-256")>

<cfoutput>#sitesecurity#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: If you are trying to match the Hash from ColdFusion and PHP see this post - [hash function that works identically on ColdFusion MX7 and PHP 5.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036931/hash-function-that-works-identically-on-coldfusion-mx7-and-php-5-x) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the link Miguel-F posted will fix your issue.  Coldfusion's hash output is in all uppercase where most (all?) other outputs I've seen are in lowercase.  Depending on how your gateway handles case sensitivity you should try passing a lowercase hash.

```
<cfset sitesecurity = lCase(hash("test_site1234GBP"&OrderTotal&URL.ThisOrderID&"PASSWORD", "SHA-256"))>
```

Comment: HUZZAH!!! It was the lowercase problem, thankyou Travis and partial to MiguelF and Matt B

Answer (score 1):

The code should have functioned the way it is, but in my opinion it's better to create the value to hash as one big string. Appending to strings is 'costly' because each time you add to a string a new string is created and the old one destroyed. If you're processing one transaction a minute you'd never notice a difference, but it is good practice either way. I would use.

```
 <cfset sitesecurity = Hash("test_site1234GBP#OrderTotal##URL.ThisOrderID#PASSWORD", "SHA-256")>
```

Now you may have an issue getting a HASH in PHP to match a HASH in ColdFusion, but that's a separate issue.

Sample

```
<cfset OrderTotal = 10>
<cfset url.ThisOrderID = 50>
<cfset sitesecurity = Hash("test_site1234GBP#OrderTotal##URL.ThisOrderID#PASSWORD", "SHA-256")>
<cfdump var="#sitesecurity#" abort>
```

Returns

```
92A14E1D03833CB3FD6932A8E240861CDEC66E46723A544DFBC3C592D5EE7E66
```

Comment: thankyou! tried this but the double hash values found at 'OrderTotal##URL.ThisOrder' cause a invalid cfml error

Comment: can you post the error? It's valid CFML using CF10. I posted a working example in my answer.

Comment: Matt, my mistake it worked I missed a quotation out. Thankyou! It is frustrating though our secure payment gateway still aren't taking the hash

Comment: can you output the two hashes created? PHP is probably returning lower case and ColdFusion upper case. Hopefully that's the only difference. You can fix by using `lcase()` on your ColdFusion hash

Comment: Thankyou Matt, yes indeed the lowercase output was where it was going awry. I love this place!