# Hash Function that works identically on ColdFusion 10+ and PHP 7.x?

Tags: php, hash, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, sha512

I am currently working on a new PHP site for a site currently utilizing ColdFusion 10.  When the new site is ready the ColdFusion site will be decommissioned and I won't have access to anything related to ColdFusion.  I don't want to have to reset all the previous passwords so need to be able to duplicate the one-way SHA-512 hash that is utilized in ColdFusion in PHP.

This question on Stack Overflow is very relevant to this problem:
[hash function that works identically on ColdFusion MX7 and PHP 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036931/hash-function-that-works-identically-on-coldfusion-mx7-and-php-5-x)

The difference is they manually looped in 1024 iterations in ColdFusion.  The ColdFusion site I am translating uses the built in iterations feature.  I have tried what they did in the above question, plus a few variations including XOR in the end but ultimately I can't find documentation on what ColdFusion is doing during those iterations.

ColdFusion:

```
<cfset hpswd = Hash(FORM.npswd & salt, "SHA-512", "UTF-8", 1000) >
```

PHP (without iterations logic):

```php
$hpswd = strtoupper(hash("sha512", $npswd.$salt));
```

Given this password: `q7+Z6Wp@&#hQ`

With this salt: `F4DD573A-EC09-0A78-61B5DA6CBDB39F36`

ColdFusion gives this Hash (with 1000 iterations): `1FA341B135918B61CB165AA67B33D024CC8243C679F20967A690C159D1A48FACFA4C57C33DDDE3D64539BF4211C44C8D1B18C787917CD779B2777856438E4D21`

Even with making sure to strtoupper with PHP I have not managed to duplicate the iterations step so the question, what operands is ColdFusion 10+ doing during the iterations step?

Comment: Have you considered writing a ColdFusion webservice that returns the hashed password to PHP?

Comment: I hadn't, but in general the main idea is to completely remove ColdFusion from the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of language, a `SHA-512` hashing function should return the same output given the same inputs. Here, it looks like you may just need to ensure that your inputs are the same. This includes the encoding of the text you are inputting. Then you'll hash over it the same *total* number of times.

As of today, the CFDocs documentation of ColdFusion `hash()` is incorrect, but I have submitted a correction for that. See my comments above about why I believe Adobe lists their defaults this way. A Default of 1 Iteration is correct for Lucee CFML, but not for Adobe CF. You are correct that the ACF default is 0. CF2018 clarifies this parameter.

Now, to your issue, your original code in ACF10 is:

```
<cfset hpswd = Hash(FORM.npswd & salt, "SHA-512", "UTF-8", 1000) >
```

This says that you are `hash`ing with the `SHA-512` algorithm, using `UTF-8` encoding, and repeating an additional 1000 times. This means that your `hash()` function is actually being called 1001 times for your final output.

So:

```
<cfset npswd="q7+Z6Wp@&##hQ">
<cfset salt = "F4DD573A-EC09-0A78-61B5DA6CBDB39F36">
<cfset hpswd = Hash(npswd & salt, "SHA-512","UTF-8",1000) >

<cfoutput>#hpswd#</cfoutput>
```

Gives us `1FA341B135918B61CB165AA67B33D024CC8243C679F20967A690C159D1A48FACFA4C57C33DDDE3D64539BF4211C44C8D1B18C787917CD779B2777856438E4D21`.

https://trycf.com/gist/7212b3ee118664c5a7f1fb744b30212d/acf?theme=monokai

One thing to note is that the ColdFusion `hash()` function returns a HEXIDECIMAL string of the hashed input, but when it uses it's iteration argument, it iterates over the BINARY output of the hashed value. This will make a big difference in the final output.

https://trycf.com/gist/c879e9e900e8fd0aa23e766bc308e072/acf?theme=monokai

To do this in PHP, we'd do something like this:

*NOTE: I am not a PHP developer, so this is probably not the best way to do this. Don't judge me, please. :-)*

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$npswd="q7+Z6Wp@&#hQ";
 $salt = "F4DD573A-EC09-0A78-61B5DA6CBDB39F36";
$hpswd = $npswd.$salt ;
for($i=1; $i<=1001; $i++){
   $hpswd = hash("SHA512",$hpswd,true); // raw_output=true argument >> raw binary data. 
        // > https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php
}

echo(strtoupper(bin2hex($hpswd)));
?>
```

The first thing I do is ensure that the encoding we are using is UTF-8. Then I iterate over the given input string **1+1000** times. Using the `raw_output` argument of PHP `hash()` gives us binary representations each loop, which will give us the same final output. Afterwards, we use `bin2hex()` to convert the final binary value to a hexidecimal value, and then `strtoupper()` to uppercase it. Giving us `1FA341B135918B61CB165AA67B33D024CC8243C679F20967A690C159D1A48FACFA4C57C33DDDE3D64539BF4211C44C8D1B18C787917CD779B2777856438E4D21`, matching the CF-hashed value.

Also note that CF returns an uppercase value whereas PHP is lowercase.

And final note: There are better methods for storing and using hashed passwords in PHP. This will help convert between CF and PHP hashes, but it would probably be better to ultimately convert all stored hashes into the PHP equivalents. https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

**=============================================================**

**A point of clarification:**

Both Adobe and Lucee changed the name of this parameter to clarify their intent, however they behave differently.

Lucee named the parameter `numIterations` with default 1. This is the total times that `hash()` will run.

In CF2018, with the introduction of Named Parameters, Adobe renamed the parameter `additionalIterations` from the original (and still documented) `iterations`. The original improper parameter name didn't matter prior to CF2018 because you couldn't use named params anyway. On their `hash()` documentation page, their verbiage is "Hence, this parameter is the ***number of iterations + 1***. The default number of additional iterations is 0." (emphasis mine) The behavior has always (since CF10) matched this description, but there is clearly some confusion about its actual meaning, especially since there is a difference with Lucee's behavior and with Adobe's incorrect initial name of the parameter.

The parameter name `iterations` is incorrect and doesn't work with either Adobe CF 2018 or Lucee 4.5 or 5.x. And this is a function that is not currently compatible as-is between Lucee and Adobe ColdFusion.

The important thing to remember, especially if working with both Adobe and Lucee code, is that this function with the `???Iterations` named param specified will produce two different outputs if the same-ish code is run. Adobe will run a `hash()` one additional time vs Lucee. The good news is that since the param names aren't the same, then if they are used, an error will be thrown instead of silently producing different hashes.

```
hash("Stack Overflow","md5","UTF-8",42) ;
// Lucee: C0F20A4219490E4BF9F03ED51A546F27
// Adobe: 42C57ECBF9FF2B4BEC61010B7807165A

hash(input="Stack Overflow", algorithm="MD5", encoding="UTF-8", numIterations=42) ;
// Lucee: C0F20A4219490E4BF9F03ED51A546F27
// Adobe: Error: Parameter validation error

hash(string="Stack Overflow", algorithm="MD5", encoding="UTF-8", additionalIterations=42) ;
// Lucee: Error: argument [ADDITIONALITERATIONS] is not allowed
// Adobe: 42C57ECBF9FF2B4BEC61010B7807165A
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hash.html
https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/hash.html

Comment: Thank you Shawn, I think more SO questions would benefit from answers like this that clearly answer the question and go beyond a basic answer.  For the future we plan on using PHP methods of storing the hash. The only thing I would note is that mb_internal_encoding is not enabled in PHP by default (will 500 a page if not enabled) but is definitely the way to go if you need to ensure your encoding matches with the encoding in ColdFusion.  Having the benefit now of your answer, not converting between hex and binary and back to hex each iteration makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Wilderness Thank you for making me have to think hard about something I'd taken for granted. Hashing is always fun because the entire point of hashing is that your output isn't recognizable, so it can be a challenge to match up two different types of hashing.(Even if it's between Adobe CF and Lucee CF). :-)

Answer (score 1):

See https://cfdocs.org/hash "...in Adobe CF the value is the number of additional iterations."

Comment: That page is actually inaccurate as the default iterations is 0 not 1: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hash.html  The question isn't how many additional iterations, but what logic is occurring with those iterations.  In the similar question the user was doing additional iterations and was hashing the previous hash with the salt.  ColdFusion's iterations do not match that but might include it.  I just don't know as I can't find documentation on what exactly it does behind the scenes.

Comment: What if you don't specify `iterations` in CF? Do you get the same hash that get in PHP, given you're using the same `SHA-512` algorithm?

Comment: @Wilderness I recently updated that CFDocs page and it's waiting on a pull request approval. 

Adobe seems to have interpreted "iterations" rather literally, so that 1 "iteration" is actually repeating a process 1 additional time, thus 2 runs of the process. Lucee CFML treats "iterations" differently as the total number of times the `hash` function is run.

Comment: Both have changed the parameter name to match their actual function: Lucee is 'numIterations' or the total number of times `hash()` is run. Adobe 2018 is `additionalIterations` or the _ADDITIONAL_ number of times to run `hash()`. 

Adobe's docs are currently incorrect (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hash.html), but they do mention it being additional runs of `hash()`.

Comment: My guess is that if you change your PHP code to run 1001 times, you'll get the same value as your ColdFusion code.

Comment: Also make sure that your encoding matches the encoding of the CF function - "UTF-8".